# MyEtherWallet and transfer of Token (CLO) question

Tags: myetherwallet

I cannot transfer my CLO to my new Ledger from MyEtherWallet. i get the not enough gas error even though i have .5 of ether on the same wallet. most likely i am missing something simple. can see the tokne (CLO) but in metamask it give me some crazy amount of 21 million ethereum instead of cLO when i go to send callisto.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Steve

Comment: Can you post the CLO token Smart contract and your wallet?

Comment: i am sorry, how can i do that. thank you for your help.

Comment: I have checked the CLO token on market cap, I thought it not on ETH blockchain network. 
Which CLO token you have, put your address wallet here